# TomEE Plus seems not find the "ejb-jar.xml" in application war

Tags: annotations, openejb, apache-tomee, ejb-jar.xml

My main aim is to migrate an EJB 2.x application written for WebSphere to a web application deployable for Tomcat server. But I want to this as nearly *one-to-one* migration.

So I set up a TomEE (apache-tomee-plus-1.0.0) and keep the configuration of the sub-directory '/apps' as deployment directory.

When I put a '*.war' file to the '/apps' directory OpenEJB successfull unpack the archive and load it. But I see no EJB loading in the logs. I think OpenEJB ignores the 'ejb-jar.xml' in '/apps/BdbWeb/META-INF'.

Log-Snip:

```
INFO main OpenEJB.startup.config - Extracting jar: C:\Entwicklung\apache-tomee-plus-1.0.0\apps\BdbWeb.war
INFO main OpenEJB.startup.config - Extracted path: C:\Entwicklung\apache-tomee-plus-1.0.0\apps\BdbWeb
DEBUG main OpenEJB.options - Using default 'openejb.tempclassloader.skip=none'  Possible values are: none, annotations, enums, all or NONE or ALL
DEBUG main OpenEJB.options - Using default 'openejb.webservices.enabled=true'
DEBUG main OpenEJB.options - Using default 'tomee.jaxrs.deploy.undeclared=false'
DEBUG main OpenEJB.options - Using default 'openejb.webservices.enabled=true'
DEBUG main OpenEJB.options - Using default 'openejb.check.classloader=false'
INFO main OpenEJB.options - Using 'openejb.descriptors.output=false'
INFO main OpenEJB.options - Using 'openejb.descriptors.output=false'
INFO main OpenEJB.options - Using 'openejb.validation.output.level=VERBOSE'
INFO main OpenEJB.startup.config - Enterprise application "C:\Entwicklung\apache-tomee-plus-1.0.0\apps\BdbWeb.war" loaded.
```

When I add at least one Annotation (e.g. @Remote or @Stateful) to a Java class I see corresponding log entries. So OpenEJB found Annotations.

But there are many classes and a big ejb-jar.xml file! I want to avoid to manually put the correct Annotation to each class ... ! So I hope you can help me to find the error.

Maybe it is a *structure issue*?
I have the following structure in the war file:

- BdbWeb.war

  - pages

    - **.jsp*
  - images

    - **.jpg*
  - META-INF

    - ejb-jar.xml
    - MANIFEST.MF
    - openejb-jar.xml (created by hand; hoped this would help - but that's not the case)
  - stylesheet

    - **.css*
  - WEB-INF

    - classes

      - de

        - *directories with the classes*
      - log4j.xml
      - hibernate.cfg.xml
    - lib

      - **.jar*
    - web.xml
  - index.jsp

I already set the `openejb.servicemanager.enabled` property in 'system.properties' file to  `true` but this generated just an xml file with no entity or bean entries.

What have I to do to get the given ejb-jar.xml used by OpenEJB?

BTW: Is the self-created 'openejb-jar.xml' really necessary ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a small tweak required: Java EE 7 required location for the "EJBs in .WARs" feature is `WEB-INF/ejb-jar.xml`

Would be a good idea for us to check for this and issue a warning.  I created a [ticket for it here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-381)

Side notes:

- No, the `openejb-jar.xml` is not necessary
- Setting `openejb.servicemanager.enabled` is also not necessary

Did you see something in the documentation that indicated `openejb.servicemanager.enabled` was required in TomEE?  If so, a pointer to the doc would be great -- I'll make sure it's removed.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! I feared that this problem is to "special" and no-one could help me ...

Comment: Yay!!! It works! 
I moved ejb-jar.xml to WEB-INF and deleted openejb-jar.xml.

BTW: The property `openejb.servicemanager.enabled` wasn't set by me directly, so TomEE set it to the default value `true`. Regarding your advice I set it to `false`.

Thank you very much for your help. This little problem caused sleepless nights :-)